# Play multiple files in WPF listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, media-player

[This is how my music player looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtRKb.png)

Hello everyone, recently I'm doing a music player project on Visual Studio's WPF.
After all of basic functionality has done, now I want to make a files playlist that contains multiple files.

So, when it runs, first I click on Open File button, to choose a file(s). Then, it will be loaded in the listbox. To play that song, I can choose either I double-clicked the song in the listbox or click the song after that I click the Play button. And the lblName info under "Now Playing" changed as my song selection changed.

I have tried to googling and code it (some copied and modified), and the files were loaded in my listbox, but it can't be played at all.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFplayer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFplayer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WPF Music Player" Height="380.436" Width="507.483">
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0" Height="350" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3FF00" Offset="0.6"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Button x:Name="btnOpen" Content="Open File..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnOpen_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="131,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnPlay_Click" Height="30"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnPause" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="211,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnPause_Click" Height="30"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="291,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnStop_Click" Height="30"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblTime" Content="-----" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="371,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.471,0.295"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblBiasa" Content="Now Playing :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="(No Song...)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sliProgress" Thumb.DragStarted="sliProgress_DragStarted"  Thumb.DragCompleted="sliProgress_DragCompleted" ValueChanged="sliProgress_ValueChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354"/>
    <Slider x:Name="sliderVol" Value="0.5" Minimum="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="436,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Cursor="Arrow" Orientation="Vertical" Height="121" ValueChanged="sliderVol_ValueChanged" TickFrequency="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" LargeChange="0.1" Maximum="1"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="MUSIC PLAYER" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Volume" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkKaraoke" Content="Karaoke" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Bass Boost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="286,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.743,0.625"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="139" Margin="17,189,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="388" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="listBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
</Grid>
```

```
string[] files;

private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.AddExtension = true;
  ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
  ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
  ofd.Multiselect = true;
  ofd.ShowDialog();

  files = ofd.SafeFileNames;

  foreach (string song in files)
  {
    if (!listBox.Items.Contains(song))
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(song);
    }
  }

  foreach (var item in listBox.SelectedItems)
  {      
    lblName.Content = ofd.SafeFileName;
    mediaPlayer.Play();
  }

  DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
  timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Start();
}

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (var item in listBox.SelectedItems)
  {       
    mediaPlayer.Play();
  }
}

private void listBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  lblName.Content = (listBox.SelectedValue).ToString();
}

private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  lblName.Content = (listBox.SelectedValue).ToString();    
  mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

I wondering what things that I missed in that code. Should I add an event(s) to my listbox?

For your helps, I would like to say thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to post it. But it doesn't look like you are even telling the `MediaPlayer` what file to play. All you are doing is getting the song path, and telling the `MediaPlayer` to play -- without giving it what file to play.

Assuming the list box item is the string of the song path, you would want this.

```
    mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(item)); //item == song path(Including extension, i.e. .mp3)
    mediaPlayer.Play();
```

However, it appears you are using `.SafeFileName` as well, which would make this problematic. So you may also want to do this if we are going to set the song directly from the listbox string.

```
files = ofd.FileNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Toskr for your answer and correction!

I have modified my code and I'll share this for anybody who needs it.

```
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.AddExtension = true;
        ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
        ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.ShowDialog();

        files = ofd.FileNames;

        foreach (string song in files)
        {
            if (!listBox.Items.Contains(song))
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(song);
            }
        }

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblName.Content = (listBox.SelectedValue).ToString();
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri((listBox.SelectedValue).ToString()));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void listBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        lblName.Content = (listBox.SelectedValue).ToString();
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri((listBox.SelectedValue).ToString()));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```